# How would I call a function which returns a table and accepts a varchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a function I need to use, I'm passing in a var char and I insert records into a table called using @ValueList. However I'm not sure how to call / use this function ?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetListFromCSVString]
(            
      @csvString varchar(500)
)
RETURNS @ValueList TABLE 
(
      ListValue varchar(50)
)
AS
begin
      -- body

End
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select ListValue
from dbo.GetListFromCSVString('1,2,3')
```

Result:

```
ListValue
----------
1
2
3
```

If the parameter to your function is a field in another table you have to use `cross apply` get the list of values for each row in the source table.

```
-- Table to test on
declare @T table
(
  ID int identity primary key, 
  SomeColumn varchar(500)
)

-- Sample data
insert into @T values('1,2,3')
insert into @T values('a,b,c')

-- Use the function
select ST.ID,
       GL.ListValue
from @T as ST
  cross apply dbo.GetListFromCSVString(ST.SomeColumn) as GL
```

Result:

```
ID          ListValue
----------- ----------
1           1
1           2
1           3
2           a
2           b
2           c
```

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to pass in the variable ValueList as a table name ?

Comment: @Jules - Not sure I understand. `@ValueList` is the return value from the function not the parameter.

Comment: I've pasted in the whole function, as you can see [at] ValueList is a table name.

Comment: @Jules - Yes it is a table that is local to the function used to build a table using a string. That table is the return value of the function.